# Bert model giving CUDA out of memory error on google colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, google-colaboratory, bert-language-model

I am using the following tutorial [here](https://mccormickml.com/2019/07/22/BERT-fine-tuning/) to train and test a Bertsequenceclassifier model on a dataset of documents of varying lengths (small(0-280), medium(280-10000), large(10000 plus)) on the google collab platform using a GPU. I have been able to successfully train and test the small dataset using a maximum sequence length of 380 on 140,000 entries. When I try to train the medium dataset on the maximum sequence length which is 512 for only 1 epoch and only on 10000 entries I get a CUDA out of memory error. When I change the maximum sequence length to 400 it is able to train the model though.

I guess that obviously the length of the documents is causing this but can anyone explain exactly why this is happening and if there is any way to fix this. Thank you

RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 20.00 MiB (GPU 0; 15.90 GiB total capacity; 15.15 GiB already allocated; 7.88 MiB free; 44.38 MiB cached)

Comment: Please share a self-contained notebook that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Please post the exact error message. What happens when you try a smaller batch_size?